# How to show a validation message if vat number is invalid? (The errors variable is empty)

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this code, the $vatValidator validates the vat number. The $validator validates other request data.

For example if the user dont insert a value for the name field it will appear a validation error:

> {success: false,…} errors: {name: ["Fill all fields."]} success :
>   false

But if the user insert a invalid value for the vat no validation message appears because in the response the errors are empty:

```
{success: false, errors: []} errors :[]
```

Do you know how to show a message when the vat number is incorrect? A message like "Invalid vat".

```
$vatValidator = VatValidator::validateFormat($request->country . $request->vat);
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

$errors = $validator->errors();
$errors = json_decode($errors);

if ($validator->fails() || $vatValidator == false) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $errors
    ], 422);
}
```

Full method:

```
 public function storeInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
        ...

        $rules = [];
        $messages = [];

        if ($all) {
            $rules["name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
            $rules["surname.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
        }

        $vatValidator = VatValidator::validateFormat($request->country . $request->vat);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);


        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors = json_decode($errors);

        if ($validator->fails() || $vatValidator == false) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $errors
            ], 422);
        }

        if ($validator->passes()) {

        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);

    }
```

Comment: With " $vatErrors = $vatValidator->errors();
        dd($vatErrors);" it appears ""Call to a member function errors() on boolean".

Comment: Is VatValidator a class that you've created or from a package you're pulling in? If it's one you've created please may you show the contents of it, otherwise can you add a link to the package?

Comment: Is from a package, the package is this "https://packagist.org/packages/dannyvankooten/laravel-vat".

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The version 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures) for the validation:

```
$rules['vat'] = [
    function ($attr, $value, $fail) use ($request) {

        if (!VatValidator::validateFormat($request->country . $request->vat)) {
            $fail('Invalid vat.');
        }

    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$errors = $validator->messages();
$errors->merge($vatValidator->messages())
```

variable $error contains all error messages

Comment: Thanks but it appears with "        $errors->merge($vatValidator->messages());
" this ""Call to a member function messages() on boolean"
".

Comment: The vat validation is using a package " dannyvankooten/laravel-vat".